# Spring web development images

Tags: image, spring, web

Can anybody tell me or give me a link to go to which can tell me how to implement and display images step by step (I'm only beginning) on a webpage from a spring project

I'm using IntelliJ

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem you're having? What have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to upload images onto a webpage just like ya would if doing plain html. But when I try to put in the links to images or css files etc in the jsp file and deploy it to Tomcat, the images aren't displaying:

This is the file structure of my project:
http://imgur.com/GhPk9

This is the code I am putting in the jsp to try load the CSS
http://imgur.com/JPQDy

And This is the code I am using to try load in the image in the css file:
http://imgur.com/BdRCQ

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's the URL of the page? The one that appears in the location bar of your browser?

That is the URL to which relative locations are resolved in the HTML code. So, if the URL is `http://localhost/MyApp/foo.html`, and the URL of the CSS inside the HTML code is `../../css/style.css`, the absolute URL where the browse will try to find the CSS will be `http://localhost/MyApp/../../css/style.css`, which doesn't make sense.

I prefer always using absolute paths for images and CSS files (and other resources). Using JSTL, that makes it like

```
<link href="<c:url value='/css/style.css'/>" ...
```

The `<c:url>` tag takes care of prepending the application context (`/MyApp`) to the path.

Note that relative paths inside CSS files are not resolved relative to the page URL, but relative to the location of the CSS file itself. So the path in your CSS file is correct.